# Does the <input> placeholder have a maximum length?

Tags: html, css

I have an input field in HTML and I'm having the problem that the text I entered as a placeholder isn't fully displayed.

```html
<input id="test" placeholder="Stadt oder Postleitzahl eingeben">
```

I already tried applying margin and padding to my input field but that didn't fix my problem. So my question is whether the input placeholder has a maximum character length or how can I fix this?

```css
#test {
    padding-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<input id="test" placeholder="Stadt oder Postleitzahl eingeben">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the width of the input element isn't enough to fit the placeholder, it will be cut off.

```css
#test {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<input id="test" placeholder="Stadt oder Postleitzahl eingeben">
```